# Same Actor with multiple roles

Tags: human-factors

What is the best way to represent two actors, of which sometimes it could be the same person?

I have a case where we have approver 1 and approver 2.  In most instances, #1 approves and it flows to #2.  In other instances, #1 and #2 are the same person, so they can act as both.

I tried drawing a box around the two actor icons.

Answer (score 1):

Actors are typically roles or personas and not individuals, so this case doesn't matter. Simply identify which actor(s) can perform what functions. If one person fits multiple roles or personas, then that simply falls out of your model.

Comment: It is two roles and I have drawn that.  But only one has to take action.  Thank you for the feed back.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that approver 1 and approver 2 are not descriptive of the difference in the roles. It's easy to read that and think two approvers are required.

Say we're talking about an assembly line that is making fuzzy bunny slippers (I like bunny slippers. Yeah I know. Stop looking at me like that)

As the slippers come down the line the heads and ears are attached to the slippers. Then they are sprayed with a light pink dye because well they're bunny slippers.

*When the head and ears are attached approver 1 must inspect that the head and ears are formed and attached correctly. Approver 2 must inspect the light pink dye.*

Said like this it sounds like they're required to be different people.

*After they're attached, a head and ears approver inspects their shape and attachment. After they're sprayed a color approver inspects the dye color on the slippers.*

Said like this it's clear these are roles. It says nothing about who is or is not allowed to perform these roles. Done like this, if that's important you can say, and change, that elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In my models I have "actors" human, organisations or even assets that have relationship natures.
This best reflect reality and we have never had a model brake over this. As in life a relationship nature is bound by a date period as well.

some samples:
Persons A is supervising account 1234. 
Then the relationship started on Date and ended on Date as the relationship expired as Person A's status changed, promoted, left organisation etc.

Person A is having a role of "account manager" 
Look for persons that have a role of "account manager" that also have a active relationship in the same org unit person A has a association.

Same can be done with rental cars and clients.. you may need to maintain a record in case you get a police ticket,

or in persons renting a home, 1 home several occupants that may have more than 1 home.

Telephone numbers, 1 number, at a given time several "owners"

I have taken one of the models (banking) at the BOM level to show the pattern

[image: Business object model (BOM) higlighing user relationship nature]

in this model nature is managed to also "fluently" express "need to know" principle as if your relationship limits the data you can see in the database as you as a user and your relationship can't generate a join to the data if in the wrong org unit or below in the Organisations-Hierarchie.

Transforming the business object model to a more concrete implementation you would get specific to your language so that ideally would differ making use of the compiler/ database features.

[image: Logical Data Model (LDM)]

In our case we transfered this into the following physical model

[image: Physical data model (PDM) showing the BOM user management and roles]

This pattern is, when you think of it, quite easy. I have used it to implement applicable tax law (what laws are applicable (from ->till).

User recommendations (what experiences does he have with related product) offered -> accepted -> expired etc.

Fraude Detektion finding insurance fraude in regards to automobile domain.

It's always the same you take a "Role Player" playing "A Role" and see that as a "relationship nature"

Have a [look](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqeBLgyZtSGag41SZSbKwWY1f8tpag?e=Q80Czd), perhaps it can inspire you

Comment: I have uploaded the domain to a public folder, you should be able to study it in more details like this https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqeBLgyZtSGag41SZSbKwWY1f8tpag?e=Q80Czd